# How to fix "ITunesSoftwareServiceAuthenticationErrorDomain error 504."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to validate an app in XCODE, but this error occurs: "ITunesSoftwareServiceAuthenticationErrorDomain error 504."

[image]

Comment: 504 means timeout error, check your connection

Comment: It looks like networking/server problem. Try again later.

Answer (score 0):

It's server error.Can you please clean the build and try again to upload with Application loader tool or Xcode.